# How to create a roof of two lines in css?

Tags: css

How is it possible to create a roof like in this image in css?
Please help.

[image]

Comment: Read this - > https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: roatation, skew, svg, pseudo-element, etc etc ... a small google search and you get it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gkwhqpno/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a box, color a corner with a border, and rotate/reposition it.

```css
.roof {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2.5em);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="roof"></div>
```

Comment: you can change the transform origin to bottom and avoid the translation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **[absolute-positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)** in conjunction with the CSS **[`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)**.

Note that you'll want to `rotate` one line 45 degrees to the right, and one 45 degrees to the left (using a negative rotation).

```css
#line1 {
    width: 200px; /* Length */
    height: 5px; /* Thickness */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 190px; /* #line2 width - both heights */
    background-color: black;
    
    /* Rotation */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#line2 {
    width: 200px; /* Length */
    height: 5px; /* Thickness */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    
    /* Rotation */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="line2"></div>
```

Comment: and how the left values are calculated ? :)

Comment: ^ It's the `width` of the line on the left minus a bit. I believe the 'bit' is the combination of the two `height` values, but it depends how much you want the lines to overlap (which in itself is controlled by how thick they are). I've updated my answer to cover that.

Comment: so in other words it's not easy to know this value as it will depend in may parametres ;) ... by the way it's not the like that .. the correct calculation is = left of first line (50px) + sqrt(2)*(200px)/2 [140px] = 190px ;) ..and it's has nothing to do with height of lines, only the width